# Phase Portraits for repeated eigenvalues

Tags: calculus

So I've just been introduced to the concept of phase portraits; and after having done the content for real eigenvalues, and then complex eigenvalues; I've now moved onto repeated eigenvalues.

I know that there are two cases: M is a multiple of the identity matrix, and M is not a multiple of the identity matrix.

For the case where M is not a multiple of the identity matrix, there is only one eigenvector: **$w_{1}$**, and trajectories which start on this eigenvalue converge to (or diverge from) the equilibrium point along this. The exercise I've  been given is to show that the general solution is:

**w(t)** = $\alpha_0$$t$$e^{t\lambda}$**$w_1$** + $\beta_0e^{t\lambda}$**$w_2$**, where **w(0)** = $\beta_0$**$w_2$**, and for a general trajectory $w_2$ is a vector not parallel to $w_1$.

My question is, how do I do this? I'm really not sure.

Comment: You're talking about two-dimensional linear systems, I suppose? What is $M$? Are you assuming that $M$ already has Jordan normal form?

Comment: Not sure about the second part, but M is just. Like, say I have du/dt = 2u + 5v, and dv/dt = -2u. Then M would be the matrix (2 5;-2 0)

Comment: OK. So you're not assuming anything about $M$ to begin with (other than that it has a double eigenvalue and $M \neq cI$). Then the first step would be to make a change of variables to bring $M$ to a simple standard form, which you would then know how to handle. This should be explained in whatever course material you have. Are you following any particular textbook, for example?

Comment: Not following a textbook, and it was in a module last year but I don't have access to that module's information. So unsure of what to do

Comment: Did you try simply googling “linear system double eigenvalue”? As I said, this is explained in lots of places. Or [search just on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+linear+system+double+eigenvalue), and you'll find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440136/two-dimensional-linear-differential-equation-with-1-eigenvector), for example.

Comment: I looked at this here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedEigenvalues.aspx; but it doesn't seem to resemble the general solution that I have found, so I'm a bit confused

Comment: It's the same as yours. Their vector $\vec{x}(0) = c_1 \vec{\eta} + c_2 \vec{\rho}$ corresponds to your $\mathbf{w}(0)$.